# strpos does not return correct results while string is available

Tags: php, csv

I am trying to retrieve a list of words strpos should look for from a file, like this:

```
foreach ($words_array as $words_key => $word_value){
    foreach ($lines as $line_num => $line) {
        $line_as_array = explode(",", $line);
        echo $word_value;
        if (strpos($line_as_array[2],$word_value) !== false) {
            echo "blabla";
        }
    }
}
```

$words_array comes from a textfile:

```
offline
online
Backup
backup
```

Now my `line_as_array[2] also comes from a text file:

```
website is online
website is offline
website backup has failed
website backup is complete
```

As a result I expected it to echo "blabla" but instead of getting any result I get absolutely nothing back. Did I make a thinking mistake somewhere?

to recap; I want to check if a string contains a substring - and then echo "blabla" based on if it does.

Comment: Without your data it's hard to say anything. We don't know what `$lines` contain and what `$words_array` contain

Comment: put your `$words_array` and `$lines` values here.

Comment: may be there is a problem of white space . try this `(strpos($line_as_array[2],trim($word_value))`

Comment: How did you populate the `$words_array` variable?

Comment: Thank you all! whitespacing was the issue! sorry about not giving all correct variables.

Answer (score 0):

I changed some code to set data as you wrote (I commented loops):

```
<?php

$words_array = ['offline',
'online',
'Backup',
'backup'];

foreach ($words_array as $words_key => $word_value){
//foreach ($lines as $line_num => $line) {
//$line_as_array = explode(",", $line);
$line_as_array[2] = 'he website is now online';
echo $word_value."<br />";
if (strpos($line_as_array[2],$word_value) !== false) {
echo "blabla";
}
//}
}
```

and for this data I get output:

```
offline
online
blablaBackup
backup
```

So for `online` word in `$words_array` you get `blabla` info because word `online` is asubstring of the sentence `he website is now online`. So it seems to work fine.